# Complex class hierarchies in C#

Tags: c#, class, hierarchy, class-hierarchy

I have to create the class model which will contain 4 classes - Database, Schema, Table and Column, something like:

```
public class Database
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public List<Schema> Schemas { get; set; };
    public List<Table> Tables { get; set; };
    public List<Column> Columns { get; set; };
}

public class Schema
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public Database Database { get; set; }
    public List<Table> Tables { get; set; };
}

public class Table
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public Schema Schema { get; set; }
    public List<Column> Columns { get; set; };
}

public class Column
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public Schema Table { get; set; }
}
```

Well, the class hierarchy is pretty easy: Database->Schemas->Tables->Columns

As you can see there are the "Tables" and "Columns" - lists in the Database - class which should contain all tables and all columns in the database.

What is the better way to synchronize the Database.Tables - list and the Schema.Tables - list? And the Database.Columns and Table.Columns lists?
It should be possible to add a new table to the Database.Tables and to see the new table in the according Schema.Tables - list. Or to add a new table to the Schema.Tables and see new table in the Database.Tables list.

I can define the Schema.Tables property as:

```
    public List<Table> Tables
    {
        get { return Database.Tables.Where(p => p.Schema == this).ToList<Tables>(); }
    }
```

But in this if I add new table to the Schema.Tables it will not appear in the Database.Tables list.

What is the better way to solve this problem?

PS. Sorry for my terrible English!

Comment: Those should be `ReadOnlyCollection`s.

Comment: Why not just use the Dataset type? its already formatted with tables rows and columns.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182142

Comment: *What is the better way to solve this problem?* Honestly a better way would be to not create this problem in the first place. Why do you *need* to be able to add a table to `Database` or to `Schema` and have it show up in the other place? That seems like a design that will cause you a *lot* of grief.

Comment: For example, if you add a table to `Database`, which `Schema` is it supposed to be added to? Have `Database` expose `Schema` *only*. Have `Schema` expose `Table` *only* and have `Table` expose `Column` *only*. If you want to add a table, then you need to first get the `Schema` you want and add it there. If you *really* want to, you could add a `AddTable(Table t, Schema s)` method to `Database` as a helper method that would add a table to the schema or something like that.

Comment: The Schema is the mandatory property of the Table. If I add the new Table to the Database.Tables it should appear in the according Schema.Tables list.

Comment: By the way - this it the typical behaviour of EF - classes. I can add new record to the, for example, dbContext.Orders and will see it in the dbContext.Customers.Where(...).Single().Orders and vice versa.

Comment: @user3807316: You are misunderstanding what EF does there. It doesn't add it in two places. It adds it in one place and it can track the relationships between tables.

Answer (score 5):

Storing data in multiple places and then trying to synchronize them is one of the two hard problems in computer science (naming, off-by-one errors, and cache invalidation).

Unless you need actual lists in `Database` just enumerate them:

```
public class Database
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public List<Schema> Schemas { get; };

    public IEnumerable<Table> Tables 
    { 
         get { return Schemas.SelectMany(s=>s.Tables); }
    }

    public IEnumerable<Column> Columns 
    { 
      get { return Tables.SelectMany(t=>t.Columns); }
    }
}
```

Comment: By the way just to understand why I need this solution.
I have a pretty complex repository which will be stored in the SQL Server database. Now I use EF6 CodeFirst to work with the repository.

In the next version I will store the repository in the XML or JSON file and my first idea was just to take a EF CodeFirst model, modify it and serialize to the XML file.